# Sharing a network connection of PC To a mobile Android device via USB Cable

Tags: internet, connection-sharing

I want to share my PC internet with mobile through USB. But I am not able to see any sharing tab in network connections. My operating system of PC is Windows 8 and My mobile is Android Kit Kat Version 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

that process is called reverse tethering. It require you to root your android devices first.

Anyway just click this <[link](http://gadgetstouse.com/how-to-2/reverse-tether/10450)> and try yourself. REMEMBER , THIS PROCESS ONLY WORK ON ROOTED ANDROID DEVICES. GOOD LUCK HAVE FUN :D